# Visual Studio shows warning in vctmp file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, warnings

I have a C# project opened in visual studio. We are using TFS to manage our projects. In one source code file of the project I have configured a warning in the following way:

```
#warning expand for all properties
```

When I compile my project the warning is shown in the error list twice. Once in the original file, and once in a file called `vctmp2984_94722.cs`. I can open the temporary file in visual studio and it has a previous state of the file.
Opening the file in explorer is not possible, cause the path of the temporary file points to a place that does not exist: C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Temp\TFSTemp\vctmp2984_94722.cs

Does anybody nows how to solve this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Did you have a "compare" running (with the "Diff - xxx") window open when you kicked off your build?  I noticed that I was getting this---a ton of vctmp errors in a project called "Miscellaneous Files", but when I closed the Diff window they all disappeared.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find a diff window anywhere for the corresponding file. But `Window > Close All Documents` fixed it for me. If you really don't want to close everything try closing and reopening VS.

Comment: This answer sorted me out perfectly. Build was working fine minutes before then the errors tarted appearing (in temp .cshtml files). Closed my diff window and all back to normal.

Comment: This is still an issue sometimes exactly 6 years on. Had to close all documents again. There must be a longstanding bug never fixed.